# Fetch post block/field data as JSON with Wordpress API

Tags: php, block-editor, api, json

Usually find what I need from here without asking but seem to have run into something new, apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I am building a site in wordpress which isn't my usual CMS but seems straight forward enough. I'm trying to get the post data using the API accessing the data at /wp-json/wp/v2/pages/24 which is great until we get to the actual content itself. The block/page content comes only as fully rendered with html. I tried using different context but this seems to either do nothing or throw a permissions error.

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of the below but cant seem to find that anywhere. Is this just not what's available or am I missing the point of this API all together? Any help would be great!

```
"content": {
"blocks": {
  "cover": {
    "classes": "wp-block-cover has-background-dim",
    "background-image": "https:\/\/localhost.local:8890\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/07\/92977310_Preview.jpeg",
    "content": "Our Range Title"
  },
  "image": {
    "classes": "wp-block-image",
    "image": "https:\/\/localhost.local:8890\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/07\/976545678.jpeg",
    "alt": "This is the alt for the image"
  },
  "layout": {
    "classes":  "background-green",
    "columns": 2,
    "content": [
      {
        "image": {
          "classes": "wp-block-image",
          "image": "https:\/\/localhost.local:8890\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/07\/976545678.jpeg",
          "alt": "This is the alt for the image"
        },
        "paragraph": {
          "classes": "",
          "content": "This is the <strong>paragraph for</strong> the left column."
        }
      },
      {
        "image": {
          "classes": "wp-block-image",
          "image": "https:\/\/localhost.local:8890\/wp-content\/uploads\/2020\/07\/976545678.jpeg",
          "alt": "This is the alt for the image"
        },
        "paragraph": {
          "classes": "",
          "content": "This is the <strong>paragraph for</strong> the right column."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"protected": false
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but if anyone is stumbling around the Wordpress Rest API like I am, here's a quick snippet you can add to the functions.php file on your theme to add a `blocks` field on the return post/page data.

```
add_action(
    'rest_api_init',
    function () {

        if ( ! function_exists( 'use_block_editor_for_post_type' ) ) {
            require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php';
        }

        // Surface all Gutenberg blocks in the WordPress REST API
        $post_types = get_post_types_by_support( [ 'editor' ] );
        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            if ( use_block_editor_for_post_type( $post_type ) ) {
                register_rest_field(
                    $post_type,
                    'blocks',
                    [
                        'get_callback' => function ( array $post ) {
                            return parse_blocks( $post['content']['raw'] );
                        },
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Resulting in the following JSON being returned from fetching a single post:

```
"blocks": [
        {
            "blockName": "core\/paragraph",
            "attrs": [],
            "innerBlocks": [],
            "innerHTML": "\n<p>Here is the story content for section 1.<\/p>\n",
            "innerContent": [
                "\n<p>Here is the story content for section 1.<\/p>\n"
            ]
        },...
```